# Stack Pane: Adding Canvas and Imageview does not result in the two being stacked

Tags: java, javafx, canvas, imageview, pane

I've attempted to add an image view and a canvas to a pane in javafx, where the imageview is animated to follow a path transition. However the animation is played way off from where the canvas is. What could be the cause of this?

Creating the stackpanne with both the canvas and walking sprite.

This is edited code very similar to mine displaying the issue only using a circle instead of an image

```
public class issue extends Application{
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(500,500);

    GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
    File file = new File("src/Image.png");
    gc.drawImage(new Image(file.toURI().toString()),0,0);

    Circle circle = new Circle(32,32,32);

    Line path = new Line(circle.getCenterX(), circle.getCenterY(),0,0);
    PathTransition move = new PathTransition();
    move.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
    move.setNode(circle);
    move.setPath(path);
    move.setAutoReverse(false);
    move.setCycleCount(1);
    move.play();

    root.getChildren().addAll(canvas,circle);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,500);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
} }
```

The animation code follows the same formula to place the sprites so i don't understand why the image is in a different location from the character art.

Some screenshots of what it looks like executed:
Character drawn on canvas where he is meant to be

[image]

Character's walk animation way off the canvas regardless of being drawn on same/similar coordinates
[image]

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @kleopatra, this should be minimal reproducable code. Draw on the canvas at any given point and the same point for image view and the problem occurs

Comment: Ok @kleopatra, i've edited the code, this time it shows the issue using a circle all you need to do is add an .png image called Image.png into the src folder to see the problem. The x, y cordinates of the circle are way off from the canvas

Comment: the stackPane lays out its children at the center - in this example, to move the circle into the upper leading edge, you need a path from circle center to -centerX, -centerY.